# Does `min-width` not work on form `input[type="button"]` elements?

Tags: html, css, forms, button, input

Anyone see a reason why this isn't working? (works with `width`, just not `min-width`)

```
input[type="button"] {
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

**EDIT:** clarification

- "button" selector works with `width`,
  just not `min-width`
- `min-width` works with other elements, just not
  "button" selector
- This is on
  chrome/safari.  Not an IE issue.

Comment: This is on Chrome/safari- min-width works, just not on the button selector

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html says that IE5 doesn't have support, while IE6 has minimal support. All othes *should* be fine.

Comment: Could you post a jsFiddle? This works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/MKGCV/

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this problem too. `min-width` does work, but might not give you the results you expect or might appear not to work due to buttons having a default `box-sizing` of `border-box`. Try setting `box-sizing: content-box` on the button.

Comment: My problem was exactly with `box-sizing`

Answer (score 3):

While investigating [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18243939/901048), I found that altering the `border-color` property of a button also enables the `min-width` CSS property in Chrome. (It also disables several built-in properties, like the default button background color, so use with caution.)

Answer (score 2):

min-width should work perfectly, you just can't see effects maybe because you make min-width less than width.. anyway example for fine html code:

```
<input type="button" style="width:50px;height:5em;min-width:40px;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes... it does work provided you style it this way:

```
input[type="submit"], button, .button, a.actionlink {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Arial","Verdana","Helvetica","sans-serif";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    min-width: 85px;
    -moz-outline: 0 none;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered like this issue and find the way to fix.
But using button tag, not input.

```
input[type="button"] {
    min-width:100px;
}
```

--[change to]-->

```
button {
    width:auto;
    min-width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple answer here:

```
.button-class {
    box-sizing: unset;
    width: 100%;
    /* additional style properties */
}
```

This will set the width to be 100% of the parent. Basically you just need to `unset` the `box-sizing` property that prevents you from setting the `width` property. This solution works with `<input type="button">` `<input type="submit">` and `<button>` HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

`min-width` isn't supported and/or is buggy in older versions Internet Explorer.

You can see a [compatibility table here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-width).

Here is an example of `min-width` being used on a `form` element, it is always wise to set a `width` property to it too.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TAG index</title>

<style type="text/css">

.example {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 500px;
}

textarea {
  height: 10em;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<p>minimum width:500px - maximum width:600px</p>

<form method="POST" action="example.cgi">

  <p><input type="text" name="item1" class="example"></p>

  <p><select name="item2" class="example">
    <option value="select1">Select1</option>
    <option value="select2">Select2</option>
    <option value="select3">Select3</option>
  </select></p>

  <p><textarea name="item3" cols="50" rows="10" class="example"></textarea></p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```