# min-width is not working in button

Tags: html, css, web

Following code is not working:

```
button {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

But, when I add `background-color` like below, `min-width` is working.

What is the reason? (I tested in google chrome 64.0 in mac)

```
button {
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Tested in chrome 6.40 ( on windows though ). https://jsfiddle.net/z2dtdwgg/ Works fine...

Comment: yes. I tested with codepen in windows that works fine.
but when I test this in mac that is not working. but I don't know the reason.

Comment: Interesting further info: if you set `width`, it works just fine. It just is fussy about `min-width`. This is mentioned in passing at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20006156/49478 Not sure what the why is. But a workaround would probably be to set `width` and `min-width` to confirm if the `min-width` gets used.

Comment: Here's what worked for me that is the closest to it working as expected: `button {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: inherit;
}`

Comment: This is indeed very mysterious...

Comment: How do you know it is not working?

Comment: I tested same code made with codepen in windows and mac.
in windows that works fine. in mac that is not working.
I've used google chrome in both platform.

Comment: and my question is why min-width is working when I add the background-color.
and I tried some solution from the stackoverflow something like width: auto but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: of course when I add background-color: inherit or background-color: red like I mentioned, this is working.
If I add background-color, then that will make some effect except bg color?

and even if I add the width property, min-width is ignored.

Comment: It doesn't appear to impact any other user-agent stylesheet values, just `background-color`. Doing some digging, I found that the default background color in chrome on macOS is `buttonface`. When I tested my earlier suggestion but with that value : `button { width: 50%; min-width: 300px; background-color: buttonface; }` , the initial width (50%) works fine, but if I narrow the browser width far enough, it actually messes up the entire page when it hits that minimum width. So I think `buttonface` and `min-width` don't play nice together.

Comment: Also, it's really weird writing buttonface over and over again, because it looks like buttface.