# How do I get min-width to work on a button in Chrome? (macOS)

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

A related question was asked seven years ago, with the last (unfortunately not helpful for me) response in 2015: [Does `min-width` not work on form `input[type="button"]` elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268776/does-min-width-not-work-on-form-inputtype-button-elements)

I'm hoping that by now there's a better answer.

I've got this very simple CSS:

```
button {
  min-width: 80px;
}
```

Which is being completed ignored, at least by Chrome on macOS (it works in Firefox, and Chrome on Windows). If I inspect one of these buttons, the `min-width` property is indeed set, but it just isn't doing anything.

Some of the tricks mentioned in the old thread above sort of work, but they have unwanted side effects. For instance, explicitly setting `width` as well as `min-width` has an effect, but then buttons with long text get word-wrapped instead of growing wider.

Changing the border color works (weird that that does anything), but it screws up the rounding of the border, and probably wouldn't be consistent across browsers anyway.

So, now that a few years have passed, does anyone know any better tricks to get `min-width` to work for a button in Chrome on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

are you using `<input type="button" value="save" />` **OR** `<button>Save</button>`?

Both css working for me. Try this. It will help you.

```
input[type='button'] { min-width: 180px;}
button { min-width: 180px; }
```

Comment: I'm using the latter, `<button>Save</button>`. I tried adding `input[type='button'] { min-width: 180px;}` anyway, but that didn't help. Then I tried using `input` instead of `button`, and that didn't help either. Did this work for you with Chrome? Maybe the problem is just Chrome on macOS.

Comment: yes it is both work for me in chrome. if possible share your code. I will help you to fix this bug.

Comment: Thanks. The code is on Github, but the latest changes haven't been pushed yet. I'll post a link after I push what I've been working on.

Comment: OK, please keep in mind this code is only half done! You can see it running (to the extent it now runs) at https://weather.shetline.com/. The code is at https://github.com/kshetline/aw-clock. Click on the gear icon to see the dialog where I'm trying to set the minimum width of the buttons. The CSS is in `styles.scss`.

Comment: By the way, I just verified the problem is only on macOS. Now that I put the code up on my site, it was easy to test it on Windows. No min-width problem there.

Comment: Sorry. But I don't have mac os.