# Dropdown font-size not increasing on ipad

Tags: php, html, css, ipad

I have a drop down where font-size is not affecting only on ipad. i tried to change the ipad font-size settings also  but it's not working. The "font-size:20px" is affecting only on the first option(please select:).

Code:

```
$sql_user="SELECT * FROM users order by first_name asc";
$result_user=mysql_query($sql_user);

?>
<form>
<div id="divUsername" class="textInputContainer" style="margin-top: 80px;"><select name="users" onChange="showUser(this.value)" style="width: 250px;outline:0px;height: 23px; font-size:20px;border: none;background: #F4F4F4; margin-left:-5px; margin-top:-1px;">
<option value="">Please select:</option>
<?php while($row_user=mysql_fetch_array($result_user)){?><option value="<?php echo $row_user['id'];?>"><?php echo $row_user['emp_code'].' - '. ucfirst($row_user['first_name']).'&nbsp;'.ucfirst($row_user['last_name']);?></option><?php }?>

</select></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9778151/1434964

Comment: Hi Natalie, Thanks for the reply. I tried select {-webkit-appearance: none; } but still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'font-size:20px' in option tag
E.g.
..
Hope this will help you.